# Bonded devices do not appear in the connected devices list of settings on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My Android application can call `BluetoothAdapter`'s `getBondedDevices` method to retrieve a list of bonded BLE devices that I know have no names. However, if I look in settings -> connected devices, I don't see these devices appear in the settings UI. Therefore, I'm unable to "unbond" them. Any ideas on why these bonded devices wouldn't show up in the list? Could it be because these peripheral devices advertise with no names? I'm using Android 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my phone (Android 10) I had to turn on "Show Bluetooth devices without names" in the developer options under "Networking".

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks. Seems crazy that this isn't available as a non-developer though... As a follow-on question, do you know if I can programmatically "name" a bluetooth device to avoid such an issue?

Comment: Hm strange. I have that option too in developer options, but I can see devices without name in the list of I press "show all".

Comment: @ChristopherHunt if my answer is good for your question you should mark it as best answer, for renaming the device you need to use the hidden method setAlias for the class BluetoothDevice. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41586433/9419048